# *ngFor throwing errors and secondly image not getting resized

Tags: html, css, angular, visual-studio-code

Iam using Angular. Im using *ngFor in order to create six product case (3 lines with 2 columns):

```
  <div class="Game">
    <div class="UpgradeContainer">
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Unlock')">Unlocks</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Cash')">Cash</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Angels')">Angels</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Managers')">Managers</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Investors')">Investors</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductContainer">
      <app-product *ngFor="product of products" [product]="products"></app-product>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it throws the following errors

Here is where I have an unsolvable error for my *ngFor. I want to precise that I'm using it in order to create six product case (3 lines with 2 columns):

The first error is:

```
{
    "resource": "/d:/AngularProject/src/app/app.component.html",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the \"@NgModule.declarations\".",
    "source": "ng",
    "startLineNumber": 27,
    "startColumn": 7,
    "endLineNumber": 27,
    "endColumn": 70
}
```

Message:

Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".

The second error is:

```
{
    "resource": "/d:/AngularProject/src/app/app.component.html",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'app-product'.\n1. If 'app-product' is an Angular component and it has 'ngFor' input, then verify that it is part of this module.\n2. If 'app-product' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.\n3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.",
    "source": "ng",
    "startLineNumber": 27,
    "startColumn": 20,
    "endLineNumber": 27,
    "endColumn": 48
}
```

Message:

Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'app-product'.
1. If 'app-product' is an Angular component and it has 'ngFor' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-product' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

**My second problem** is i cant resize the product images.

Here is an image of the disaster:

[Image that does not resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg6KH.png)

Here is the code that I used:

```
.ProductImage{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="Product">
  <div class="ProductImage"> <img src="./assets/Avatar.jpg"> </div>
  <br>
  <div class="ProductNumber">ProductNumber</div>
  <br>
  <div class="ProductPrice">ProductPrice</div>
  <br>
  <div class="ProductProgressBar">ProductProgressBar</div>
</div>
```

Here is my directory structure

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWLGv.png)

Thanks in advance for anybody that would be kind enought to help me.I'm  a beginner in HTML/CSS/Angular.
Have a good day.

Comment: You didnt give a class to img ,better you give a class to it and apply css

Comment: Can you share your code so I can run it in my machine and tell you whats going on or the link of stackblitz?

Comment: Ohh I understand now why I can't resize image thanks. And how do I share the code, do I copy each file content and put it in my question topic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <app-product *ngFor="let product of products" [product]="product"></app-product>
```

As for the image resizing , give a separate class to image tag

```
  <div class="ProductImage"> <img class="product-image" src="./assets/Avatar.jpg"> </div>
```

and 
CSS

```
.product-image{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%
}
```

Comment: Perfectly works and I see where my errors where by the way. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome...if you found this answer correct , upvote it and mark it as correct.

Comment: Can't upvote since my reputation is not enought sorry mate... but I marked it as correct :D.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the ngFor issue you need to import BrowserModule in the module where you declare your component. In your case it's probably app.module.ts

Make sure to add these:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductComponent],
imports: [BrowserModule],
})
```

Comment: I already did it. But it seems like the errors came from the syntax of my app-product balise.